# I'm getting two session ids in one session with Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a controller called `CartController.php`
In this controller I have two methods:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
        // we'll check to see if the order is already in db
          $productOrderDetails = new \App\Cart;
          $productOrderDetails->session_id = session()->getId();
          $productOrderDetails->job_name = $request->jobName;
          $productOrderDetails->pro_name = $request->productName;
          $productOrderDetails->save();
          return response()->json($request);
  }

  public function displayCart()
  {
    //dd($upsCost);
    $currentSessionID = session()->getId();
    $displayCart = Cart::where('session_id', $currentSessionID)->get();
    dd($currentSessionID);
    session(['inCartDetails' => $displayCart]);
    return view('layouts.cart')->with('cartDetails', $displayCart);
  }
```

The store method is hit by a fetch api post.

```
 export async function postProductDetails(details) {
  const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cartDetails';
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(details)
  })
  if(response.ok) {
    window.location.href = "/cart";
  } else {
    alert("HTTP-Error: " + response.status);
  }
  // return response.json();
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting two different session ids.
When the method store is hit via the fetch post I get the session id:

```
HnSxCjSXflzyt4Uks3SGsEZcJEHleSR97N1RNA5l
```

Then when I run the method displayCart it gives me a different session id:

```
su8A6E3umTW1XmXf5Yhk3SHU5WUGCEpcJWXlnVIP
```

It's being accessed from same browser, with in a couple of minutes.  Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on the session ID for your logic, You could however create a Cart and save the Cart ID to the session and then retrieve it:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $productOrderDetails = new \App\Cart;
        $productOrderDetails->job_name = $request->jobName;
        $productOrderDetails->pro_name = $request->productName;
        $productOrderDetails->save();
        session(['cart_id' => $productOrderDetails->id]);
        return response()->json($request);
    }

    public function displayCart()
    {
        $displayCart = session('cart_id') ? Cart::find(session('cart_id')) : null;
        return view('layouts.cart')->with('cartDetails', $displayCart);
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, are you insinuation session id isn't reliable?

Comment: From what you describe, it looks like it - give a try to my solution see if it works

Comment: But how would the cartId be generated and linked to the current session?

Comment: See the updated answer  Please accept the answer if that solves your question

Comment: This would create a challenge thou.  Let us suppose two users are on the cart and they both select the same product.  There would be a potential for conflicts.

Comment: 2 different users would get 2 different sessions, so 2 different carts. You may however have issues if the user wants to create multiple carts, but this is a different issue.